# Is there any way to set up load balancer for only 2 web: site1 and site2?

Tags: iis, load-balancing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jFHf.png)
This is what i did

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCmnT.png)
i've try to use general url rewrite to make server farm that only serves for domain nlb.xyz but i still stuck? please help me to solve this, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use below condition that will help you allow only specific domain to use load balancing url rewrite rule:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer but i've solve this problem by add more conditions:  server port doesn't match 8081 and 8082

Comment: glad to hear that issue is resolved. you could adjust and modify the condition based on the  site url.